# Building SANE from git-source produce backend missmatch on 12.04 even if built locally

Tags: 12.04, install-from-source, sane

It seems to me that with Ubuntu Precise Pangolin it is all but easy to do a proper install of SANE from source (git-repo).

I've found other scanning issues trying to find an answer to this, where the output people posted seems to indicate they suffer the same issue (unknowingly).

If I run on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 with compiled SANE source from the 
git I get:

```
$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.24git; backend version 1.0.22
```

(I basically followed the instructions on
http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/02/how-to-get-an-canon-canoscan-lide-100-scanner-to-work-in-ubuntu-11-10linux-mint-12.html
since I didn't find any other information making sure that sane was not 
installed prior to installation.)

My primary interest is the epson2-backend. In 1.0.22 it offers the wrong  TPU settings for Epson V700 (TPU2-mode wasn't supported in 1.0.22, and the scanner is useless to me if I don't have the TPU2-support).

Since if I ask it to enter transparency mode, it shows 1.0.22 behaviour, it implies that the epson2-backend comes from 1.0.22 and not 1.0.24 even though I just built it.

If I install SANE with prefix to a local folder and run that version of scanimage it still produces the mismatch.

However, on another computer where I installed a custom 1.0.22 build of 
SANE prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, I can build and install the same SANE-git locally and have it correctly match backends:

```
$ ./SANE/bin/scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.24git; backend version 1.0.24
$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.22; backend version 1.0.22
```

On this computer the 1.0.24 works correctly in finding TPU2 on Epson V700.

So what am I missing/doing wrong?

(And I want to replace 1.0.22 with 1.0.24 for the whole system, the local build was just debugging.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

Just tried compiling SANE using [this instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource) on Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked like a charm. However, when I upgraded to 12.04 (really would like to run 12.04), SANE was downgraded to 1.0.22. When trying the same set of instructions on 12.04 I was still out of luck -- the backend missmatch was there again (and I do have libusb-dev installed)

**Edit 2:**

I updated to Ubuntu 12.10 which now has the 1.0.23 SANE drivers. I haven't dared trying to compile from source on 12.10 since 1.0.23 is good enough for me. This is just a work-around and I would still like to know what's up with Ubuntu 12.04.

**Edit 3:**

Tried building SANE on 12.10 both using the above ubuntu-guide and building to a local directory. Both attempts produced backend miss-match.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I had the same problem, this is how i fixed it.

With help from http://www.sane-project.org/README.linux

First of all, Disconnect your scanner, and start all over.
I uninstalled `Xsane`, and everything related through `synaptic`. I also uninstalled everything what was `configured` and `make install` by the `sane-backends-git`.
You do it like this:

```
    $ cd [your sane-backends-git folder]
    $ sudo make uninstall
```

After that I checked wheter or not I had any libsane.so.1 left, (and any other archives related to `sane`).

```
    sudo find / -name libsane.so.1
```

Ok , all clear.

Installing `xsane` again with `synaptic`, and some `dependencies`

```
xsane 0.998-3ubuntu2  
libsane 1.0.22-7ubuntu1
libsane-common 1.0.22-7ubuntu1
xsane-common 0.998-3ubuntu2
sane-utils 1.0.22-7ubuntu1
```

testing the output of `scanimage -V`, just for fun

```
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.22; backend version 1.0.22
```

Next steps, according to the README.linux 1.0.24.git documentation.

first locate the `libsane.so.1`

```
sudo find / -name libsane.so.1
```

And, depending on your system, take note of the folder where `libsane.so.1` is located. In my case:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1
```

then, from your `sane-backends-git` folder

```
./configure 2>&1 | tee ~/thiscommandwritesalogfiletoyourhomefolder.log
```

The `2>&1 | tee` writes a log-file to where you define it. That can come in handy, not obligated though. 
Please check the output of configure that usb is supported. This info
comes with one of the last lines. If not, you need to install `libusb-dev`
now and rerun configure.

install sane-git to `/usr/local/lib/`

```
$ make && sudo make install
```

Then one of most important parts, the creation of the symbolic links. Note that here you will have to change the foldername of the one where `libsane.so.1` is located. (see above how to do that)

```
$ cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libsane.so.1.0.24 libsane.so.1
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/sane/libsane.la libsane.la
$ cd -


copy udev rules file
$ sudo cp tools/udev/libsane.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
```

reconnect your scanner to the usb bus

join group scanner

```
sudo adduser [YOU] saned
sudo adduser [YOU] scanner
```

and `logoff` and `login` again

that should do it. 
`scanimage -V` should give the latest libsane backend, and Xsane should work with no problem.

Hope it helped you.

And **Note**, If you have problems with Xsane shutting down, just delete the in your home folder the hidden file .sane, type `Ctrl-H` in `nautilus`, and you will find it.

Comment: Sorry for rather late reply here, this seems to at least on the surface resolve the incompatibility but I'm not sure if the compiled SANE actually will work and have permissions on newer versions of Ubuntu. I will have to verify further before accepting the answer